# Save large numeric output to file natively in Julia 1.0.0

Tags: file-io, julia, hpc

I am trying to run a program in hpc-cluster. Unfortunately, I am unable to install external packages (e.g., JLD2) on the cluster. This is is a temporary problem, and should get fixed.

I don't want to wait around all that time and I am wondering if there is any way to save large output (2-3 GB) in Julia without external dependencies. Most of the output is matrix of numbers. I was using JLD2 previously that stores data in HDF5 format.

Bonus question: Is there a workaround to this using shell commands, like use pipe to get the output and use awk//grep to save data? (something like `julia -p 12 main.jl | echo "file"`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the [`Serialization`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Serialization/index.html) standard library.

To work with multiple variables, you can just store them sequentially:

```
x = rand(10)
y = "foo"

using Serialization
# write to file
open("data.out","w") do f
    serialize(f, x)
    serialize(f, y)
end

# load from file
open("data.out") do f
    global x2, y2
    x2 = deserialize(f)
    y2 = deserialize(f)
end
```

or you could put them in a `Dict`, and just store that.

Comment: this is great and it works for my purpose! But I don't understand what does `f` mean? Is that just a temporary object? Can I use any other character?

Comment: It's a file handle: see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/index.html#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments-1 for more information on do blocks.

Answer (score 4):

You could [write](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.write) as binary. Something along the lines of

```
julia> x = rand(2,2);

julia> write("test.out", x)

julia> y = reshape(reinterpret(Float64, read("test.out")), 2,2)

julia> x == y
true
```

If it is just HDF5 that is missing you could use for example [NPZ.jl](https://github.com/fhs/NPZ.jl).

Comment: Yeah, this is fine, but it gets messy with large number of output variables. I liked the JLD format where you could save all the workspace variables as output, and read it in different languages like python or matlab. 

I somehow can't install packages in my cluster account for now, so NPZ would not work.

Maybe I'll write each variable manually as you suggest. My source code is not written by me so it is a lot of trouble to manipulate variables.

Thanks though!

Comment: Do you have file access? Just download the package (and dependencies) locally and upload to `.julia` folder.

Comment: That is a great idea! This way I won't have to mess around with the variables. I'll try this.